# Send SMS using GPRS

Tags: gprs

In our project presently we are sending and receiving SMS messages using GSM system(mean, by some third party SMS service provider through URL ). but now we need to migrate it to GPRS system.

that, we need to replace GSM by GPRS system. we do not know how the architecture 
will be. In GSM message was send and received through URL  from out application using HTTP
API's.

How can we use GPRS to send and recieve messages , please tell the way to do it.

thanks in advance ,
Mahesh

Comment: What is the diference between the method you talk here?? and how do you know that the url is gsm system?

Comment: What do you mean by gprs system?

Comment: afaik gprs is for packet data, while sms are part of the GMS standard and are therefore not sent via gprs but by using the old GSM system. sending messages using GPRS need a protocol on top of e.g. TCP or UDP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **GPRS can never send an SMS**. You can connect to any SMS gateway using GPRS which can send SMS for you, GPRS is basically internet service for GSM networks, it has a different purpose altogether. **GPRS is HTTP transport, nothing more**.

I request you to **explain the use-case scenario** of how you want to send an SMS ? Given this people here can better help you and come up with correct feasible solution.

Comment: Actually GPRS was made to support IP and PPP (X.25 in some cases). So general TCP and UDP packets works fine.
Normally MMS messages go over GPRS as well.

Comment: Right, MMS uses GPRS as transport. Majorly now a days GPRS is not preferred for TCP/UDP, it is done using EDGE or 3G.

Comment: Both EDGE and 3G (WCDMA) still use GPRS for their packet transportation.

Comment: Please, refer to the 3gpp specification 24.011 Release 12 section "2.6 MS support for SMS over GPRS". In the other words, there is support of the SMS over GRP specified. There are terminals who are capable to send it (like Nokia Symbian). Unfortunately I don't see any support of this in the Android API.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to configure your device so that it can "dial" an GPRS connection. That is like dialing a modem on a PC. Then, you should be able to send and receive data using TCP oder UDP like you would do with any other "normal" application. Some devices "dial" the GPRS connection automatically when you try to connect to a host using TCP, for other devices, you'll have to dial manually.

You just need to think in terms of "how can I exchange messages using TCP or UDP between my device and my server"  now.

Answer (score 1):

For SAGEM HiLo based GPRS Modem, you can use command

AT+CGSMS=2
// Which means Prefer Packet Domain for SMS, if not available use Circuit Switched

Comment: https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcgsms-select-service-for-mobile-originated-sms-messages/

Answer (score 0):

What I'm guessing that you are using is a SMS gateway service provider which can route incoming short messages via a HTTP/GET or POST to your destination url.

I'm using both a sms gateway service and a direct GPRS connection for my applications. In both cases they send log information. The difference is that using GPRS does not require a gateway service (since you are not sending short messages over gprs).

You just need to set up a socket server that the modem can connect to. Fortunately I found a modem with a built-in python interpreter so it was very easy to write a client (not so incidentally the socket server was also written in python).